# Google Apps Script - redirecting by «window.top.location.href» stop working

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, web-applications

This construction doesn't work in my GAS project anymore to redirect browser:

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<script>window.top.location.href='${url}';</script>`);
```

This construction works:

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<script>window.location.href='${url}'</script>`);
```

But it hides real redirected page URL behind the script URL because we are changing not the ".top" window href.

Has anyone faced this problem too?

P.S.: I tested it on several people with Chrome browser - the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue... Noticed it a few weeks ago and just did a search and found this question on Stack Overflow.  However, upon a further search it appears as though Google has disabled the ability to do this as per their September update:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases

> September 2021
> September 1, 2021
> In the HTML Service iframe sandbox, allow-top-navigation, which allows the content >to navigate its top-level browsing context, is restricted and not set as an >attribute in the sandbox. Instead, the allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation >attribute has been added to the sandbox.
>
> If you need to redirect your script, add a link or a button for the user to take >action on.
>
> Learn more about HMTL Service restrictions.

However, it appears to me like it still works in some circumstances.  I have a application with about 30 pages or so and it appears on some pages it still works. Have not been able to find out the reason though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!AFAIU if you application is still working it is not a feature but more like a bug, unfortunately. And may be soon construction `<script>window.location.href='${url}'</script>` will stop work because it is still can be considered as perform malicious redirection and must be restricted.